# Intersection chip

Tags: sequence

In Sequence:

I can play a chip to make two sequences at the same time, but one sequence is an extension of an existing one (which means I am using one red chip from the first sequence).

Can I make these two sequences with the one chip? e.g., can I play my green chip on the 3 of hearts, circled, below?

[image: section of a Sequence board showing chip placement]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what game it is you're playing here?

Comment: Please describe in detail what an intersection coin is and how it works and what it has to do with the red, green, and blank (circled) pattern of your image.

Comment: It’s sequence game

Comment: Though I don't play the game, the question as asked is perfectly understandable to those who know the game in question. If we start closing questions because we personally don't understand what's being asked due to not having the frame of reference, just about everything on this SE will get closed by someone who doesn't play that game. I wouldn't expect non go players to know what komi is for instance, it's not a reason to close because they don't understand.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson That image is a rough diagram of the tokens already laid out on a sequence board (as shown in the unfortunately low res image below it) It sounds like this is a game you know nothing about (I don't either, my cousin's family plays it though) but your lack of specific game knowledge doesn't make this question bad.

Comment: @doppelgreener I checked the edit history, this post never had a tag edit history, and was tagged with the game being played since it was originally written (though it wasn't mentioned in the question, it probably should have been) Sequence is a specific board/card game

Comment: @Andrew *"If we start closing questions because we personally don't understand what's being asked due to not having the frame of reference, just about everything on this SE will get closed by someone who doesn't play that game."* No need for slippery slope, dude. The question appeared to name a game, but the content of the game does not match _any_ visuals I can find when searching by that name. I closed for more information. We got more information and confirmation. It's being reopened. We _do_ have community moderation here, and it's going to happen.

Comment: @Andrew , I've played Sequence. But you're right about a lack of reader knowledge not in and of itself making the question bad, but it also helps quite a bit to use the terms from the game: "chips" or "marker chips" instead of "intersection coin", for example, to avoid such confusion.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Yes, in fact prior to closing the question I even tried searching for those terms. "Intersection coin" and "sequence intersection coin" match no useful results in Google at all, so I concluded it was unclear what was going on. The question's pretty clear now.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson based on the question wording, im guessing English is not Karthik's native language, and both token and chip may translate the same for them.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, almost assuredly. And, to help make the question helpful and part of this SE, I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: (FWIW, I voted to close because I consider myself very familiar with the game and I couldn't figure out what was being asked. The vivid image of the board was not visible when I saw the question, and I was the first to vote IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

You can make two sequences with the same chip, yes.

From [the rules](https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/):

> you may use any one of the spaces from your first SEQUENCE as part of your second.

(It uses "first" and "second" here to refer to the two sequences. This usage doesn't not imply that simultaneously-completed sequences are excluded.)

**But**:
Also note that a sequence is five chips of the same color, so in your example, you're only completing the vertical sequence. The horizontal set is just four green chips in a row and so is not yet a full five-chip sequence.

> A connected series of five of the same colored chip either up or down, across or diagonally on the playing surface.

Comment: +1 but worth a note, that 4 in a row seems to be the result of multiple edits not by the original poster.  The original post image had 2 5 in a row.  Ironically in the current state it is worth calling out :)  Honestly, I just envisioned a chit on the 3 of clubs that was off screen til you did so tho.

Comment: @joedragons, The current edit accurately reflects the original. Note that the original question's image showed four, exactly like the current picture and the original text of the post emphasized the specifics about the sequence being four of green and the fifth of red: "which means one red coin I am using from 1st sequence"

Comment: Thanku L.scott Johnson for editing my question, and explanation.